# Insert values in a pandas dataset from certain dates in a dataset column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Good night. I have a Dataset with dates from 01Jan19 to 20Jan19. I want to fill the temperature value of the day 01Jan19 to 10Jan19 with the value 15.75. And from the day 11Jan19 to 20Jan19 with the value 20.60.

Below is the code I made:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

base = pd.read_excel('Teste_ABC.xlsx')

if base.loc[(base.Dia >= '2019-01-01') | (base.Dia <= '2019-01-10')]:
    Base['Temperatura'] = 15.75
else:
    Base['Temperatura'] = 20.60
```

The following error message appears:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I fix this?

Grateful for the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code cannot work because when you do `base['Temperatura'] = 15.75` you replace the entire column.

Also `base.loc[(base.Dia >= '2019-01-01') | (base.Dia <= '2019-01-10')]` is not a single value but a subset of the rows of your dataframe, not a boolean, that's why you get the error message.

You can achieve what you are trying to do by using

```
base['Temperatura'] = np.where((base.Dia >= '2019-01-01') | (base.Dia <= '2019-01-10'), 15.75,20.60)
```

The first argument of `np.where`is the condition you want to match, second is the value for when it matches and third the value when it doesn't match

Another solution if you want to use `loc`:

```
# here you replace the rows that matches the criteria but you select at the same time the column Temperatura only
base.loc[(base.Dia >= '2019-01-01') | (base.Dia <= '2019-01-10'),'Temperatura'] = 15.75
# similar code for the other condition
base.loc[not ((base.Dia >= '2019-01-01') | (base.Dia <= '2019-01-10')),'Temperatura'] = 20.60
```